# How to use a php function to get posted values

Tags: php

I'm new in php and i have an issue in creating a form and geting the posted values.

1. I have two pages login.php and display.php
2. I need to display in the display page the two values i have inserted on login page using a php function.

### >How can I use `GET` to retrieve my values?

Thanks for your answer.

what i realy whant to do is this:
login page:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="./display.php" method="Post">
    <h3>

    <fieldset>
<?php
       echo"<label for='username'>Username:</label>";
       echo"<input type='text' name='username' id='username' size='10' title='Username' />";
       echo"<label for='password'>Password:</label> &nbsp";
       echo"<input type='password' name='password' id='password' size='10' title='Password'/>"; 
function getvalue(){

// i want to use this function to get the username and password

}      
?>
</fieldset>
<br>
<a id="myLink" title="forum" href="./display.php" onClick="getvalue()";return false;">link text</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

what shoul i do, i know that what i wrote is so incorrect

Answer (score 1):

If your form is something like this:

```
<form method="get" action="display.php">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="password" name="password"/>
</form>
```

You can use php in `display.php` like this:

```
<?php
  echo $_GET['username']."<br />";
  echo $_GET['password']."<br />";
?>
```

If you use this option, your URL would look like:

```
http://example.com/display.php?username=something&password=somethingelse
```

This is **NOT** what you want.

However, I would use `POST` as it is more secure.

You can do this by changing the method to:

```
method="post"
```

and in `display.php` changing it to:

```
echo $_POST['username']."<br />";
echo $_POST['password']."<br />";
```

The URL will look like this then:

```
http://example.com/display.php
```

**NOTE:** Just so you know, **do not ever** send a `password` over `GET`! This is just an example. Anyone who does this is an idiot.

Comment: Maybe generally correct, but don't ever send passwords via GET!

Comment: Updated answer just as you commented! @deceze

Comment: How about you update it to use POST?

Comment: True, I'll do that now. I was just answering to reflect OP's question (asking for `GET`) @deceze

Comment: Yes, answering the OP's question about using GET is fine, but as the OP is new to PHP I think there needs to be some education as to WHY we use POST and GET...